# Prove there is a unique natural number n so that 1/(n+1) ≤ r < 1/n.

Tags: real-analysis

Let r be a real number satisfying 0 < r < 1. Prove there is a unique natural number n so that 1/(n+1) ≤ r < 1/n.

I know I have two things here to prove. I need to show that there is an n that exists, and then I also need to show uniqueness. I think that once I find existence, uniqueness should be fairly easy to prove because I would just have to show that if I have two natural numbers that exist, then they must be equal. So here the main thing I need help with is showing existence.

Comment: Since this is equivalent to showing $n+1\ge \frac{1}{r}$ and $n<\frac{1}{r}$, I think you probably want to use the Archimedean Property to conclude that there is an integer $m\ge\frac{1}{r}$, and then use the Well-Ordering Principle to conclude that there is a smallest positive integer $k\ge\frac{1}{r}$.  (Then let $n=k-1$.)

Comment: @user84413, There is the issue that $r$ could be irrational, so I don't think we can employ the Well-Ordering Principle.

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem; if you let $T=\{j\in N:j\ge\frac{1}{r}\}$, then T is nonempty by the Archimedean property, so T has a smallest element by the Well-Ordering Principle for N.

Comment: Does this follow from the disjoint union $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\Big) = (0,1)$?

Comment: I have been given a proposition: For any real number r there exists a unique integer n such that n </= r < n+1. Can I use this proposition for the proof of my problem since. 1/n+1 </= r < 1/n can be rewritten as n < 1/r </= n+1?

Answer (score 1):

**Existence**: let $m=\frac{1}{r}>1$. If $m$ is an integer, let $n=m-1$ so that $n<m\leq n+1$ (in this case the $\leq$ is actually $=$). If $m$ is not an integer, let $n$ be the integer part of $m$ so that we again have $n<m\leq n+1$ (in this case, the $\leq$ is actually $<$). In either case
$$
n<m\leq n+1\implies \frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{m}=r<\frac{1}{n}.
$$
**Uniqueness**: if $n'\in\mathbb{N}$ also satisfies the $\frac{1}{1+n'}\leq r<\frac{1}{n'}$, then
$$
\frac{1}{1+n'}\leq r<\frac{1}{n}\implies n<1+n';\\
\frac{1}{1+n}\leq r<\frac{1}{n'}\implies n'<n+1.
$$
Together these imply $n<1+n'<n+2$. So it must be that $1+n'=1+n$; that is, $n'=n$.